# Using different css/include files for mobile

Tags: php, mysql, css, mobile

I'm working on a dynamic page that has millions of pageviews every month.  This page has been designed for a desktop website.  We want to make a mobile friendly layout of the page, and conceptually are thinking about approaching it this way:

Example:   site.com/my-profile.php?name=steve

The actual page has only 1 line of code, which references an include file, which has the actual code of about 1000 lines that runs the page:

```
 <?php require_once('/home/abcdefg/public_html/profile_page_body.php'); ?>
```

We'd like to be able to identify if the user is mobile and if so, then serve up a different include file that's better formatted for mobile users.

```
 <?php 
 if (....what do I put here to say:  mobile=="no".......) {
 require_once('/home/abcdefg/public_html/profile_page_body.php');}
 else 
 require_once('/home/abcdefg/public_html/mobile_profile_page_body.php'); 
 ?>
```

So, if the mobile is not detected, it would just load the current body include file.  If mobile were detected, then it would load a different body include file.  In that new/different body include file, we could then play around with the width of the screen, font-size, etc. to make it display more appropriately on mobile.

Assuming that logic isn't flawed solid, then the issue is:  How do we identify that the user is coming from a mobile device.

I found this:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

I assume I could change the last line from this:

```
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

to this:

```
 require_once('/home/abcdefg/public_html/profile_page_body.php');}
 else 
 require_once('/home/abcdefg/public_html/mobile_profile_page_body.php');
```

This whole process saves us from having to create mobile subdomains and deal with different urls and all that stuff.

Is this approach acceptable?  Is there trouble in approaching it this way?

Lastly, is that method of identifying the user as mobile a good one, or is there a better method?

Comment: I just want to mention, from a usability perspective, to make sure you have a way for users to *opt-out* of using the mobile version. Nothing is more annoying than being forced to view a page optimized for a 3.5-inch screen on a 10-inch tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecting Devices is kinda old in this day and age, responsive is the way forward. Rather than detecting this and that, you should focus on providing your content to people using CSS styling.

The design industry really has moved along speedy to accept mobile browsing and the answer to that is Responsive Design.

I don't know what kind of CMS your using but all themes can be adopted to use http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ or http://foundation.zurb.com/ both of which are free and used by hundreds of 1,000s already. I seriously recommend you reconsider or consider a responsive design for ranking purposes and your viewers in mind.

With your method its near impossible to cater for all mobile phones and only the major ones since with responsive they fit all by detecting the width of page, none of this detecting mobile.

Comment: Hi, this answer was not the answer to the specific question I asked, however, after a week of reading up and experimenting with responsive design, I do think it is the direction to take for us versus the detecting devices.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No Problem Kevin, GL with your Project ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the PHP libraries that do mobile detection.

Here is one:
http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: Thanks, this looked perfect, but designed to play around with media queries and responsive design instead.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, you're better off doing responsive design with CSS media queries.